# UA741 output voltage

Tags: voltage, operational-amplifier, output

I am trying to calculate the output voltage of a UA741 with non-inverting input 5V and inverting input 3V. As I understand, Vout = Aol * (V+ - V-), but because Aol is very large and my op-amp is fed with +-10V, I was expecting my output to be just 10V. When I tried the circuit on a breadboad I get a voltage that is not even close to that.

Could someone give me a little push on understanding what part (if not all) of my experiment is wrong?

Comment: It is absolutely necessary to use resistive negative feedback.

Comment: With no feedback, your opamp is working as a comparator, so you should expect its output to be at either one extreme or the other. But if you refer to a datasheet for the archaic 741 you'll find that those extremes are not all that close to its supply rails - a few volts away in most cases.

Comment: What voltage do you get? I would expect +8(ish)

Comment: Yes, I intend to use it as a comparator indeed. If i plug it 5 and 3 V I get an output of 9.4V. If i swap the inputs (3 and 5 V) I get -8V. The thing is I would like to make sense of these figures analytically, but I don't see how...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What goes wrong is that you assume that you have an ideal op-amp in your hands that has an output that can go right up (and down) to supply voltages.

No such thing exists in real life and all opamps have outputs that can only go somewhat near the supply voltages.

How near depends on the op-amp model.

You have an archaic op-amp model designed in 1960s, more than 50 years ago. The output cannot go near supply voltages by design. The data sheet tells a reasonable expectation would be 2-3 volts less than supplied voltages.

More modern op-amps may boast a feature called rail-to-rail output, which means the output can go much more near to supply voltages by design, meaning maybe few tens of millivolts.

Since you said you will use the op-amp as comparator, please note that op-amps make really poor comparators. If you put too much difference between inputs, the op-amp may work unexpectedly and give a false comparison result.

If you want a comparator, use a comparator instead of an op-amp.

Comment: Thanks, @Justme, very useful response!

Answer (score 1):

I would expect an output voltage of roughly 9V with +/-10V supplies and no load on the output. There were/are a number of 741 makers and they may vary somewhat.

According to this [datasheet](https://www.ti.com/lit/ds/symlink/ua741.pdf), you are only guaranteed a swing of +/-12V over temperature with +/-15V supplies, so with +/-10V supplies, +/-7V would be a reasonable lower limit.

So if you insist on using this part as a comparator your circuit should accommodate that (in fact you should accommodate the full range from +/-7V to almost +/-10V).

For example, if you wanted to feed it to a 0/5V TTL or CMOS input you could add a BJT, diode and a couple resistors to provide appropriate output levels.

Comment: Thanks for your response, @Sphero!